NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController State Restoration Timing
I am using NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController objects in my Cocoa app. I have implemented state restoration for the NSWindow and it appears to be working correctly as previous NSWindow objects along with their size and position are correctly restored.
I have also implemented state restoration in NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController subclasses by overriding encodeRestorableState(with:backgroundQueue:) and restoreState(with:) method. It works fine but I am having trouble with the timing.
My NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController objects drive the detail NSViewController, similar to how a sidebar does the same thing using delegation design pattern.
I managed a collection of NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController objects in the container NSViewController of the detail NSViewController rather than in the NSWindowController subclass.
My NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController objects contain a collection of NSButton controls so that is why I am using state restoration to restore the state of the NSButton, e.g. which NSButton state is switched on and which NSButton are switched off. Only one NSButton can be switched on.
The problem is by the time I have restored the state of the NSButton controls in the NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController object, the container NSViewController is using the default fallback NSButton, which is the first NSButton in the NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController object.
How can I make the container NSViewController use the restored state of NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController instead of the first NSButton as if the app was launched the very first time? Because the detail NSViewController doesn't not reflect the NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController object selection.
Using print(_:separator:terminator:) statements in various places in NSWindowController, NSSplitViewController, NSViewController and NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController subclasses, I noticed that NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController objects are typically restored last whereas my NSViewController business logic starts working earlier. Maybe that is why it will not be restored in time. Is there a solution? I tried moving the NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController objects management in NSWindowController subclass and it didn't help.
